# LINQPad stops working when using LINQPad.config file

Tags: c#, linqpad

When I use a LINQPad.config file when running any C# statement, LINQPad stops working. It doesn't seem to matter what's actually in the config file. I've even tried using an empty config file and the same thing happens.

In trying to solve this problem, I discovered that calling

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile.Dump()
```

returns

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4\LINQPad.config
C:\Program Files (x86)\LINQPad4\LINQPad.config
```

This is the correct path to my config file, however I would have expected to see the path listed only once. I suspect this may be a clue to solving the problem, but I'm unsure how to proceed. In addition to installing the 32-bit version of LINQPad, I have the 64 bit version on my desktop (not installed via installer) so I'm not sure if that might have played a role or not.

Comment: Are you running that `Dump` as a C# Expression or as part of C# Statements/Program? You'll see the value repeated if you `Dump` in an Expression.

Comment: To expand upon Tims answer: If you are running this as an expression, you will see two outputs. Once because you are running the "Dump" method and once more because the "Dump" method also returns the dumped object, making it the result of the entire expression, which is automatically dumped in "C# expression".

Comment: What do you mean by 'stops working'?

Comment: @Tim, As it turns out, I was indeed running it as C# expressions and that did cause it to output the path twice.

Comment: @Joe, Sorry, I mean it crashes. Windows displays a dialog box that says the program has "stopped working".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably something wrong with your configuration file and a totally empty config file isn't valid either.

Try a minimal file such as

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's the standard LINQPad.config, in case you need it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup useLegacyV2RuntimeActivationPolicy="true">
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0"/>
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <legacyUnhandledExceptionPolicy enabled="1" />
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```